# Google Assistant broadcasting to Google Home

Tags: actions-on-google

I'd like to broadcast a message on my Google Home using the new broadcast command from a node server.

Example use would be to notify me when I receive an email, paypal notification, etc.

Is it possible to do so with Google Assistant SDK? I've tried searching for a github with similar features to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No what you want is not possible with the Google Home as there's no way to do notifications or directly invoke commands with notifications.

With the assistant SDK, you'd need a device to embed your logic. You would need to feed in audio clips telling it to broadcast some phrase and come up with a trigger for when to send that audio.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With Google assistant on my phone I can type "broadcast {message}" and it will notify all my devices on home network. Is it not possible to connect a raspberry pi running the SDK to my network and send a written command as I would on my phone?

Comment: The raspberry pi with the SDK should be able to transmit the message, but it won't receive any broadcasts.